# Why does my regex to read to a particular sequence of characters not work?

Tags: php, regex

It frustrates me to no end that I can't produce a single working regex myself. Everytime I think I understand the concept I still fail, even for simple cases. I have researched dozens of somewhat similar questions and tried all techniques, and still it does not work.

Here's the format I'm trying to "parse":

> {{Taxobox
>     Any string can be in here, but never double curly braces
>   }}
>
> Here comes a paragraph of text, it can contain any string but will never
>   contain a double equal sign (==)
>
> ==This is a header

What I'm trying to do is to extract anything after Taxobox {{ }} and before ==header. This is what I have:

```
$pattern = "/\{\{Taxobox[^\}]*\}\}(.*?)==/";
if (preg_match($pattern, $pagecontent, $matches)) {
var_dump($matches);
}
```

The result of this match is nothing. I do know that the first part, up until (.*?) successfully matches the Taxoblock. Now it's just a matter of matching everything after that until we reach the ==. I don't understand why this last part won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `s` modifier to let `.` consider also newlines, and you have to modify your expression a little, to be more precise about the `Taxobox` contents.

Let's try this:

```
/\{\{Taxobox.*?\}\}(.*?)==/s
```

Comment: That works, thanks so much! For my learning, I still wonder why this pattern works whilst mine didn't?

Comment: Simply because of the `s` modifier, that tells the engine to consider also newlines into the characters class matched by `.`. Then I modified a bit the `{{Taxobox}}` part, also if your version works too. My regex simply tells to match anything after the `{{Taxobox` string until the following part `\}\}` is found.

Answer (score 2):

While in your regex, `[^\}]*` will match *anything* but a closing curly brace, `(.*?)` will match much of anything *but* line breaks, which leads to the pattern not matching.

You might want to use the `s` modifier ([reference here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)) for the regular expression in order for `.` to include line breaks.

Comment: Thanks, currently using /m/s combined with @fge answer, but no match yet.

Comment: Odd indeed, I can't explain the difference.

Answer (score 1):

First point: this is on several lines. Add the `/s` modifier so the newline can be matched by dot.

Second point: don't use `.*?`, lazy quantifiers should be avoided at all costs.

Third point: no need to escape `}` in a character class, just write `[^}]`.

Try this regex:

```
$pattern = "/(?<=\}\})(.+)(?===))/ms";
```

Comment: The `m` modifier just changes the behaviour of the `^` and `$` anchors, what you mean is the `s` (dotall) modifier to make the `.` also match newline characters.

Comment: Why lazy quantifiers should be avoided??

Comment: I do mean `/m`, I don't use the dot in the regex. The `/s` modifier is probably useful here if it also affect complemented character classes in PHP. Does it?

Comment: @lorenzo-s because they are very expensive: they need to look forward at each and every position before they can swallow one character

Comment: Thanks for the useful hints. Unfortunately it still does not match. I don't understand what the [^(]+ part is for? Isn't that negating an opening bracket?

Comment: @Ferdy yes, to be precise, it matches any character which is not an opening bracket. The only two characters which need to be quoted in character classes are the backslash and the closing brackets, others don't need to be quoted at all -- not even the dot.

Comment: OK, so it means complemented character classes in PHP don't match newlines. Bleh.

Comment: @fge Can you link me some article about regex performance? I can't understand exactly what you mean. The lazy quantifier is needed get a as-short-as-possible match, so at the first ending character found, it stops and close that match. Greedy instead looks forward to see if there are others parts of the string that can close the match. Am I wrong?

Comment: @lorenzo-s as to the link: http://regex.info ;) As to lazy quantifiers, they are seldomly needed, they can in pretty much all cases be advantageously replaced either by a complemented character class or a positive lookahead.

Comment: @fge [php regex modifier doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), if you don't use the anchors `^` or `$` the `m` modifier doesn't have an impact on the regex behaviour. So, it does not hurt to have it, but it will change nothing.